# How do I remove this part of the table?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, pagination, html-table

I'm using the pagination-feature in ASP.NET and I wish to completely get rid of the table. I've browsed around and found that some say that it ain't possible to create a custom pagination-system to sue with the gridview and others say that it is but it's advanced. Since I'm new to ASP.NET either way will do but the best way would be if I could style it to **NOT** look like a table in CSS.

Here's what the pagination looks like in my gridview. I've marked what I wish to remove. The content inside the green box is the paging-table and the dark-grey box with arrows pointing at it is the part I wish to **remove**.

[image: I've marked what I wish to remove. The content inside the green box is the paging-table and the dark-grey box with arrows pointing at it is the part I wish to **remove**.]

Here's the gridview;

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdFAQ" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="FAQ_Id" 
    DataSourceID="oGetAllFAQs" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    PageSize="50" onrowdeleted="grdFAQ_RowDeleted" AllowSorting="True" 
        onpageindexchanged="grdFAQ_PageIndexChanged" 
        onpageindexchanging="grdFAQ_PageIndexChanging" onsorting="grdFAQ_Sorting">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#f2f2f2" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="FAQ_Highlight">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgHighlighted" runat="server" AlternateText="Highlighted (Show on front page)" 
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/flag_yellow.png"
                    Visible='<%# Eval("FAQ_Highlight") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="FAQ_Important">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgImportant" runat="server" AlternateText="Important" 
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/information.png"
                    Visible='<%# Eval("FAQ_Important") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FAQ_Id" DataTextField="FAQ_FromDate"
            SortExpression="FAQ_FromDate" HeaderText="Date" DataTextFormatString="{0:d}"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Administration/FAQEditor.aspx?FAQ_Id={0}" 
            Text=""  >
         <ControlStyle Width="75px" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="UI_medium" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>

        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FAQ_Id" DataTextField="FAD_Question"
            SortExpression="FAD_Question" HeaderText="Question"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Administration/FAQEditor.aspx?FAQ_Id={0}" 
            Text="" >
        <ItemStyle CssClass="UI_medium" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>

        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FAQ_Id" DataTextField="FAD_Question_Secondary"
            SortExpression="FAD_Question_Secondary" HeaderText="Secondary language"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Administration/FAQEditor.aspx?FAQ_Id={0}" 
            Text="" >
        <ItemStyle CssClass="UI_medium" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image" 
             DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/table_row_delete.png" Visible="false">
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="X-Small" />
        </asp:CommandField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete"
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/table_row_delete.png" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
                    CommandName="FAQ_Id" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_Id") %>' ToolTip="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#dedede" ForeColor="#000000" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="pager" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" 
            Text="Tomt! Välj ett språk.."></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Segoe UI" 
        ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f7f6f3" ForeColor="#000000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And here's the styling for the class pager and all table-related css;

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, hr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-weight: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width:100%;
}

.pager table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.pager th, td {
    /*border: none;*/
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}


.pager:hover td {
    background-color: #f7f6f3;
}
```

Here's the HTML source of the paging-table when viewing the page;

```
<tr class="pager" align="center" style="color:Black;background-color:#DEDEDE;">
<td colspan="6">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <span>1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdFAQ&#39;,&#39;Page$2&#39;)" style="color:Black;">2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see in the HTML code above, the paging-table is inside the gridview-table. Appreciate you time, thank you!

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer to your question but you really should consider using DataTables. They're a jquery plugin that's easy to set up, use them with a repeater (not a gridview) and you instantly get paging, sorting, searching. All much quicker than with the gridview alternative. Well worth checking out. https://datatables.net/

Comment: It looks really nice but I sadly can't because my employer wish to keep using gridviews. Thank you for the link! @FullTimeSkeleton

Comment: No problem, I should really be on commission for them, the amount of times I mention them as a viable alternative!

Comment: Try `margin-bottom: 0px;`

Comment: That solved it, thank you @PiLHA - Add it as an answer and I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom: 0px;` to table CSS.

Result:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
```